# How to calculate the weighted average of a raster for the pixels touching a layer corresponding to a buffer (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, buffer, raster-calculator

I have a first raster layer which represents pixels of about 30m by 30m.My second layer corresponds to a circular buffer with a radius of 500m (I calculated the buffer from a point layer)

I have a great number of buffer. For each buffer, I want to calculate the weighted average of the pixels (I want a weighted average because sometimes a pixel can barely touch the buffer, but I still want to include them in my average)

I searched the forum, but couldn't find how to do it. Does anyone have an idea/solution?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of with ESRI software would be to convert all the raster cells to polygons and calculate fractional intersection with a vector intersect deriving a given weighted statistic based on area-weights. However, computationally you may find this is rather untenable. The size of the problem could be limited by subsetting pixels to only where intersecting polygons occur, via a mask, still a less than an ideal solution and you are still stuck with performing an aggregated analysis using the fractional areas for each polygon/pixel. You may be able to find a solution using the Tabulate Area tool but there is no fractional representation, only resampling to a common resolution.

The only way I have seen to realistically perform this type of analysis, including Python, Matlab and Julia, is in the `exactextractr` R package, which is written in C++. Besides being crazy fast, the `exact_extract` function will return fractional intersection, derive weighted statistics, and allow for custom statistical functions. It is actually quite easy to read in data and perform the analysis. In R vector data is read in using the `sf::st_read` and rasters with `terra::rast`, from the sf and terra libraries respectively. Once read in extracting values and calculating say, a weighted mean, is a straightforward as `exact_extract(raster, vector, fun='weighted_mean')` which could then be related back to the polygon data and written out as a shapfile using `sf::st_write`. All-in-all, only a few lines of code so, easy entry.

Comment: THANKS ! I tested on R with the packages you mentioned and it works very well!